# Stop user use control-c to stop command line tool in swift

Tags: swift, signals, swift5, command-line-tool

I wanna stop user use control-c to stop command line tool, and do something when user press control + c. I find sth but it isn't work in the swift5

```swift
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)

        let sigintSrc = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGINT, queue: .main)
        sigintSrc.setEventHandler {
            print("Successfully created")
            exit(0)
        }
        sigintSrc.resume()
```

The `sigintSrc.setEventHandler` did't be called.

The whole code is:

```swift
func updatePM(_ showInfo: Bool, isCreatServer: Bool = false) {
    print("Start update package...")
    let id = ProgressHelper.share.creatProgress { self.printPointProgress($0) }
    
    // TODO: Stop use control-c to broke the clt
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)

    let sigintSrc = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGINT, queue: .main)
    sigintSrc.setEventHandler {
        ProgressHelper.share.stopProgress(id)
        ProgressHelper.share.join(id)
        if isCreatServer {
            print("Successfully created")
            self.printSplitLine()
            exit(0)
        } else {
            print("Stop update packages")
        }
    }
    sigintSrc.resume()
    
    do {
        let ssh = try SSH(host: serverConfig.ip, port: serverConfig.port)
        try ssh.authenticate(username: serverConfig.userName, password: serverConfig.password)
        
        if serverConfig.system == .centos {
            if showInfo {
                try ssh.execute("yum -y update")
            } else {
                (_, _) = try ssh.capture("yum -y update")
            }
        } else {
            if showInfo {
                try ssh.execute("apt-get update")
                try ssh.execute("apt-get dist-upgrade -y")
            } else {
                (_, _) = try ssh.capture("apt-get update")
                (_, _) = try ssh.capture("apt-get dist-upgrade -y")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    ProgressHelper.share.stopProgress(id)
    ProgressHelper.share.join(id)
}

// MARK: - Tool

private func printPointProgress(_ id: UUID) {
    while ProgressHelper.share.state(id) {
        ProgressHelper.share.wait(id)
        sleep(1)
        print(".", terminator: "")
        fflush(stdout)
        sleep(1)
        print("\u{0008} \u{0008}", terminator: "")
        fflush(stdout)
        ProgressHelper.share.stopWait(id)
    }
}

private func printSplitLine(_ text: String = "=") {
    if ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w) == 0 {
        for _ in 0..<w.ws_col { print(text, terminator: "") }
        print("")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper I want to execute a program. I want to do something after the user presses control-c during execution. I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: @Sweeper I Update the question

Comment: @Sweeper I have already edited it

Comment: Instead of `.main`, try passing `nil` as the `queue:` parameter. I don't know what this `ProgressHelper` API that you are using does, but it probably doesn't run the main queue.